# How to make DIV element responsive to screen resolution

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create element div that contain 3 part, using 2 row and 2 column.

```css
.flex-row {
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    width: 310px;
}

.flex-column {
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
}

.flex-body {
    display: flex;
    margin: 40px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.flex-body div:not([class*="flex"]) {
    border: 1px solid white;
    flex: 1 1 260px;
    width: 764px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-body">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div style="background: #0980cc;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-column">
    <div style="background: #09cc69;"></div>
    <div style="background: #cc092f;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I set the width because if I didn't do it, the width wouldn't fit page.

But the div isn't responsive. I've tried but nothing work. How can I make my div responsive the screen resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just created a version that uses percentages:

```
body,
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.flex-body {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 40px;
}

.flex-body div:not([class*="flex"]) {
    border: 1px solid white;
    flex: 1 1 50%;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-row {
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    width: 35%;
    background-color: #0980cc;
}

.flex-column {
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    width: 65%;
}

.flex-column div:nth-child(1) {
    background: #09cc69;
    width: 100%;
}

.flex-column div:nth-child(2) {
    background: #cc092f;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/muygrafico/cbgowz7d/1/)

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to add another one row. With height spec, first row 25%, second 50%, and third 25% but I failed set the height. I wish you can help me. Thanks